# Why Hangfire failed state is not final?

Tags: c#, hangfire

`Hangfire` `State` classes implement `IsFinal` property. When I get value for `FailedState`, it returns `False`. I'm confused.

Why `FailedState` is not final? Is it a bug?

[Code is here](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/States/FailedState.cs#L115)

Comment: My guess is that you can have retry policies and when your job fails, the failure is not final, because possible after retry it will succeed.

Comment: I got it. If job has `FailedState`, we can re-queue it. Only `Deleted` and `Succeeded` states have `IsFinal  = true`